# could not get response from express.js server using postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response, postman

when i make post request from postman, the request data was shown server but server response i.e status code and json object was not send to postman, postman was just loading... and after some time it says could not get response from the server.

here is my server.js class

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Todo} = require('./models/todo');
var {Users} = require('./models/Users');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/todos', (req, res) =>{
var todo = new Todo({
text: req.body.text
});

todo.save().then((doc) => {
res.send(doc);
}, (e) => {
res.status(400).send(e);
});

});

app.listen(3000, () =>{
console.log('started at port 3000');
});
```

Comment: What request(s) did you try to make?

Comment: Add a `.catch(err => res.send(err))` to the `todo.save()`. It's probably throwing an exception, thus not resolving the promise.

Comment: This code should be working just fine...

Comment: i make post request.

Comment: @malik so a POST to `http://localhost:3000/todos` ?  Can you please post also your contents of `./db/mongoose`?

Comment: @Paul this is the content of  ./db/mongoose.                                                                                                    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp');
module.exports = {mongoose};

Comment: facing the same problem, did you find any solution to his?

Answer (score 0):

There is some error in executing todo.save do `console.log(e)` to check what is the error throwing by mongo. Also you can send error in a response just to see what is going on, instead of writing `res.status(400).send(e);` write `res.send(e)` and it will send error as a response. "could not get response" error happens usually when you haven't send any response from the server. In your case you are sending response from your Promise resolved block but not from your error block.

Also make sure todo.save() return promise? may be you can achieve this by

```
todo.save(function(err,doc){
if(err){
return res.send(err);
}
res.send(doc);
})
```

Comment: in postman console it gave this error  Error: read ECONNRESET

Comment: Its not working I even use above code. now showing error "socket hang up"